# How to center align my display only item in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

I have display only item -> where I am printing error message of database with error code

Following is the name of my display only item : P1_NEW

**My code :**

```
Exception 
    when others then
            v_code := SQLCODE;
            v_errm := SQLERRM;
            :P1_NEW := '<h1 style="text-align:center"> Database error occured </h1>' v_code ||  v_errm ;
```

But the issue here is my error code and error message not getting center align

Only my Database error occurred is getting center align

My need is to center align my `custom text + error code + error message`

Answer (score 0):

Displaying some information to the user as part of a page but *not* as part of a form can be done with a region as well. Create a region of type "static" and  reference your item with the `&ITEM.` syntax. This gives you a lot more control over the look and feel of the message.